# Cross-validation with sklearn in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to do a cross-validation in my Artificial Neural Network (Python with [Keras](https://keras.io/)). I'm interested in the Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC) (or accuracy, for that matter) measurements over the training *and* the test data. At the moment, my code looks like this, using [StratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold):

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(n, input_dim=dim, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['matthews_correlation'])

    asd = model.fit(X[train], Y[train], validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]), nb_epoch=epoch, batch_size=10)
```

Not that I fill X[train] and Y[train] into the validation_data function of Keras. This gave me an MCC of about 0.7 for the training set and <0.10 for the test set.

Alternatively, I analyzed a test dataset with the [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) function of sklearn (with test size 20 % which corresponds to the 20 %-folds in the cross-validation above):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)

asd = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), nb_epoch=epoch, batch_size=10)
```

This gave me again a training MCC of about 0.7 but on the test also around 0.7. I would have expected them to be very similar as above.

Are those two code snippets really trying to find the same? How can it be that they are so vastly different for the same training set?

**Note**: The MCC in the first example seems to be stuck, not changing at all, whereas it fluctuates in the second example.

Comment: `StratifiedKFold()`is used to preserve the distribution of (target) classes when splitting a data-set into k-folds.  If you had 3 classes (0, 1, 2) and they were distributed 20/10/70, when you split your dataset 80/20, you want both splits to sill have a 20/10/70 distribution.  `train_test_split()` will not preserve this; it just randomly finds (in your case) 20% of the data and splits it *once*.  If your y variable is a floating point in (0,1), then try using `KFold()` instead.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm using the MCC, because I have only 10% positives (class I) and 90% negatives (class II) in my data. Accuracy isn't a good score for this asymmetrical partition. Have I fallen exactly for this problem? When I used train_test_split(), it would statistically choose many negatives from class II and so give a good validation score but when I used the StratifiedKFold(), my score is actually worse, because it's more difficult to predict a positive (class I)? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: If you have discrete classes of {0, 1} distributed 90/10, definitely use `StratifiedKFold()`.  While highly unlikely, it is possible, if you use `train_test_split()` to split your data, to get a train set with ***only*** negative classes in it.  This is really bad.  But your classifier will be amazing.  It will have an accuracy of 100%.  But when you validate it will see classes its never seen before (positive ones).  This is why you need to preserve the distribution of the training data.